# A question in Type inference in conditional types

Tags: typescript, types, type-inference

```
type CtorParamsType<T> = T extends {
    new(...args: infer U);
} ? U : any;

class MyType {
    constructor(name: string, age: number) {

    }
}

type T1 = CtorParamsType<MyType> //any
type T2 = CtorParamsType<{ new(name: string, age: number); }> //[string, number]
```

In this sample , I expect T1 and T2 will have the same type.Why they are different?

Answer (score 3):

The type you are looking for already exists, it's called `ConstructorParameters`.

Your type would have worked too, the only issue is that `MyType` is the instance type. You want the constructor parameters of the class type, which you can access using `typeof MyType`

```
class MyType {
    constructor(name: string, age: number) {

    }
}

type T1 = ConstructorParameters<typeof MyType> // [string, number]
type T2 = ConstructorParameters<{ new(name: string, age: number): any }> // [string, number]
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=8&ssc=93&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCeAVeAHAptA3gWAFDQOmAHsA7CAFwCcBXYC4qgClLAFs0AuaSqgS1IBzADTQwgrtFI02AIzRUAlFjx5C0AL54tuPBVQZEARmgBeaAGEyvOgyoAFMFXZoKCiAB596YgDM4SAYAfNAA9KHQANq8AiJSMvJUALp6BtCIAExmltbUtoyOzhxuVJ6YUmgA7iwu3DFCouKS0nIKitxgpPCaIeFR9XEtiUlAA)

Comment: MyType is instance type?

Comment: @wude, yes, meaning it is the type of an instance of the class (ie the type of the expression `new MyType(....)`. The class itself, which in JS you access just using the class name (ie `MyClass.staticMehtod` or `const cls = MyClass`), is `typeof MyClass`

Comment: how to understand "typeof MyClass".